# Effective C#: Overriding Object.Equals(), yay or nay?

Tags: c#, overriding, equals

In the second edition of Effective C# (ISBN-13: 978-0321658708) on page 37, the book reads

> *The second function you'll never redefine is static Object.Equals()*

However, on page 39, the book reads

> *The point is that if your type should follow value semantics (comparing contents) instead of reference semantics (comparing object identity), you should write your own override of instance Object.Equals()*

Would someone be so kind as to explain why one would override

```
public virtual bool Equals(object right);
```

and not

```
public static bool Equals(object left, object right);
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you can't override a static method.

Comment: Well, that would certainly be a valid reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to clear is you cannot override static methods. The implementation of

```
public static bool Equals(object left, object right);
```

cannot be overridden. The static equals method is only for connivence for not doing a null check. Internally it first checks for reference equals and then content equals(non static equals method).

In the quotes you mentioned above, the first quote refers the static equals method where as second refers non static equals method both are written in notation as Object.Equals() but notice that the first one says "static Object.Equals()"

Comment: Would it be correct to say that a non-static method is an instance method?

Comment: To answer my own question: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> never redefine **static** Object.Equals()
>
> You should write your own override of **instance** Object.Equals()

Notice the difference, *static* vs *instance*. These sentences are not referring to the same method...

Answer (score 1):

Also, if I am not mistaken, the static one only compares the reference, where as the virtual one gives you ability to write your own comparison, which most of the times are based on values rather than reference.